# How to auto-create row space / spacial definition between rows with different column values?

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I want to create a row, or some kind of definition, between Google Sheets rows whenever one of the value in my columns contain a new / different value.

[Here's an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-9Oy1aDZwvuEreZ1eXjJ7h2Yx2QD3NU7BoIHAttKJ7c/edit#gid=0) of the kind of spreadsheets I'm putting together, which shows how  Agencies are listed in **Column A**, and *Sub-Agencies* are listed in **Column B**.

I'd like to create some kind of row space / spacial definition between every **new** / **different** Sub-Agency, which are values that I enter in Column B of my spreadsheet -- but **no space** between rows with *the same* Sub-Agency value.  [Here's an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19LYzEPMSF0UiHvw8tpRDWZ7cmZNfsBKF6EPqytR0Jrs/edit?usp=sharing) of the kind of row space / spacial definition that I'm seeking.

Any ideas / suggestion on how do this?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a row after X condition.

Using [insertRowAfter(afterPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowafterafterposition) inserts a row after the row you want:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// This inserts a row after the first row position
sheet.insertRowAfter(1);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm checking it out now. So, I can configure this so that it will create a row / spacial definition based on new values created under Column B? Thanks again...

Comment: It can create a new empty row under any row you want

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I've tried it a few times but haven't yet successfully implemented it.